# Rails Elasticsearch "undefined method `model_name' for [PROXY]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, elasticsearch

I have a rails app in which I want full text searches to go to my elastic search server. I have the Elasticsearch server running with no issues and I can do full text searches on it with curl.

However, I am having issues with `'elasticsearch-model'` and `'elasticsearch-rails'`. With my model as such:

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class ConfigTextSearch 
  include Elasticsearch::Model
end

ConfigTextSearch.import
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `model_name' for [PROXY] ConfigTextSearch:Elasticsearch::Model::Proxy::ClassMethodsProxy):
  app/models/config_text_search.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/devices_controller.rb:73:in `config_text_search'
  app/metal/status.rb:18:in `call'
```

When I do a query through the application OR if I go into rails console and try to `inspect(ConfigTextSearch)`.

I tried using `class ConfigTextSearch < ActiveRecord::Base` in my model...thinking maybe the missing methods could be inherited, but then I get `NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord`.

Any ideas on how to resolve this `undefined method 'model_name'` for the elastic search rails plug in?

UPDATE: Here is the controller and how I do a search:

```
  def config_text_search
    if params[:device_id].nil?
      @devices_with_config = []
    else
       @devices_with_config = ConfigTextSearch.search params[:device_id])
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hi. How did you solve this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: ya, I got it working but I can't remember how though....to long ago. Sorry. It is fixable though.

Comment: My problem is that, i see the same error message with request specs which implements elasticsearch methods from one of my controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elasticsearch-model gem expects something that looks like an ActiveRecord object and makes a lot of assumptions about the object its included into.

You could go down the path of using ActiveModel to include the necessary functionality in the object you're using, but I'm not sure you're using it the way it expects to get used.

Usually you have a model, say a User, that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base. The elasticsearch-model gem makes that searchable *assuming* a lot about the underlying object.

ConfigTextSearch doesn't really sound like the thing you're searching -- you probably have a Config that you're searching. If that's the case, you'd include elastic search-model in Config and then you could Config.search('whatever you want to search for')